# Proper way to execute a script tag in a Knockout HTML template

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have the simple html page, where simple `ul` list defined with following viewmodel for it:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <button class="btn btn-link" data-bind="click: addItem">Add item</button>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: listItems">
      <li>
        <p data-bind="text: itemText"></p>
        <script>
          $(document)
            .ready(function() {
              console.log("new li has added");
            });
        </script>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  function ItemViewModel(text) {
    var self = this;

    self.itemText = ko.observable(text || "");
  }
  function ListViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.listItems = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.addItem = function () {
      self.listItems.push(new ItemViewModel("new item: " + self.listItems().length));
    };
  }

  ko.applyBindings(new ListViewModel());
</script>
```

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1c3prhhv/

Adding items to list work perfectly, though `script` tag in list item template doesn't work. Each time when item adds to list, I need to execute all `JavaScript` code in corresponding `script` tag.

How to properly add items to Knockout's observable array with executing `JavaScript` code in them?

Comment: This technique is very unusual, and I'd strongly recommend against it, even if it worked. What is your exact goal? Why do you need that `script` tag?

Comment: This is simple example, in real case I use kendo's Asp.Net Mvc wrapper, which strongly needs to execute js code near definition of their components.

Comment: Can't you use the `afterRender` callback?

Comment: In general MVC "controls" don't play very well together with knockout. I had very hard times to rape DevExpress grid to work with KO for example, and at the end I gave it up.

Comment: `afterRender` looks like what I need, but I can't understand, how can I execute template js code in script tag, in `afterRender` event.

Comment: Literally you can't execute a `script` tag there. In that callback you can the rendered DOM nodes, and you can do whatever you want with them, for example initialize kendo stuff, etc.