# Knockout component with <script> tag not executing after loading with binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Similar to

[Proper way to execute a script tag in a Knockout HTML template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40400887/proper-way-to-execute-a-script-tag-in-a-knockout-html-template)

As I understand things, a `<script>` tag can go anywhere in the body and will function fine on initial page load and parsing. I am using KO components, and I would like to include a `<script>` tag inside the component. I'm doing this so that I can link a component with the JS functionality, so they enter and leave the DOM together.

If I run the following, it loads AND executes the content of the `<script>` tag:

```
function loadJs(file, hash){
    var fileObj=document.createElement('script');
    fileObj.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
    fileObj.setAttribute('src', file);

    if (hash != undefined) {
        fileObj.setAttribute('integrity', hash);
    }

    fileObj.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous')
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(fileObj);
}
```

If I use the KO default loader to load/register the component, the component loads correctly but the content of the script tag does not execute. The `component` bindings are all working fine it seems:

```
ko.components.register(name, {
    viewModel: { instance: containerVm },
    template: html
});
```

Am I missing a "loading" step or something that executes the contents of the component after registering?

Comment: Your exact problem is that the script does not get fetched by the browser at all or that it does not execute something it was supposed to?

Comment: Good point...in Chrome debug console, I can see it in the elements tab, but when I look at the sources tab, it isn't there. That suggests it isn't even downloaded I think.

Comment: Is the script that you are loading within your servers domain? Or is it from an other server? Updated your post and add a "network" tab snippet, click on the request and check the "response" tab to see if any content is downloaded

Comment: Same domain. Nothing to update since I noticed that it doesn't show on the Network tab either.

Comment: I think knockoutjs cant interpret script tags, you are not supposed to call them in the knockout template, you have to define your scripts in the knockoutjs model

Answer (score 0):

For a start, open your app, navigate to where you are supposed to fetch the file, open the console in dev tools and paste the following:

```
var fileObj=document.createElement('script');
        fileObj.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
        fileObj.setAttribute('src', 'put/some/js/path/here/for/testing');
        fileObj.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous');
        fileObj.onload = function(){ console.log('tadaa');};
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(fileObj);
```

This should work fetching your file and logging the requst in the network tab.

Make sure that this function is really called by your code and maybe you can try the following:

```
function loadJs(file,hash){
    var fileObj=document.createElement('script');
    fileObj.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
    fileObj.setAttribute('src', file);

    if (hash != undefined) {
        fileObj.setAttribute('integrity', hash);
    }

    fileObj.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous');
    fileObj.onload = function(){
     // anything that requires this script to be loaded should go in here
    };
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(fileObj);
}
```

To make it more generic, you should pass the onLoad as a callback, i.e:

```
function loadJs(file, onScriptLoaded, hash){
        var fileObj=document.createElement('script');
        fileObj.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
        fileObj.setAttribute('src', file);

        if (hash != undefined) {
            fileObj.setAttribute('integrity', hash);
        }

        fileObj.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous');
        fileObj.onload = onScriptLoaded;
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(fileObj);
    }
```

Then you can pass in a callback anytime you are loading a js file, that should do whatever you want to do when the file is loaded.

Comment: Hmm, I might have mis-communicated. The `loadJs` function works fine when called manually, and everything shows up in the right places. The issue is that when a Knockout component is loaded that contains a `<script>` tag, the contents of the tag are not executed. I've since realized that my use case has changed. The way I had templated things didn't make sense to have JS loading on every page change. I think I need to revisit my issue. I may just delete this question.

Comment: well then, i failed :D happy bug hunting my friend

Comment: I appreciate the efforts. While it may not have solved this particular problem, it gave me things to think about .

Comment: Your best bet would be to manage such cases a.k.a module loading with some kind of framework. Look into requirejs for this. You could use a standarised way to manage who depends on who, who should be loaded when someone else is loaded etc within your js file ecosystem.